# Jmeter Random Ramp-up

Tags: jmeter

Im currently trying to Ramp-Up threads on a random timer but could not find a satisfying solution so far. I want to start a new thread every 4 to 12 (Random) Seconds.

Is it somehow possible to Ramp up threads based on a groovy script?

I tried using "${__Random(4,12)}" inside the Threads scheduling Parameters of the Stepping Thread Group but this is only executed once resulting in starting all the threads with the same time increment

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be going into that direction because tests need to be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability) hence using random delays in ramp-up is not something you should be normally doing.

If despite the above warning you still want to implement it I would recommend considering using a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer), if you put it [as a child of the first request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) it will introduce a delay before this request and you will be able to use [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) there but make sure to convert seconds to milliseconds like `${__Random(4000,12000,)}`

If you need to delay the **thread start** event for the random amount of time I'm afraid that this is not possible using either existing [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) so you will either need to implement your own thread group by [creating a new JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html) or alternatively you can kick off new JMeter threads from [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) like

```
ctx.getThreadGroup().addNewThread(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(4000, 12000), ctx.getEngine())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Considering your warning, you are right, I was thinking about having the random timers inside a CSV and loading them with the Random CVS Plugin into a variable. This results in the same problem tho as the thread group is started before evaluating the CSV. Problem with adding a constant timer at the start is, that it will start all timers in parallel right? That will not end up in the desired result. The timer should wait for the timer from the last thread to be triggert if you know what I mean.

Comment: I will try the JRS223 Sampler idea. So how would you set up the thread group there? Just a normal thread group and then add a new thread at the start of each iteration? Then I have the problem that they wont start parallel anymore right? They will only start once another is finished..

Comment: I think I figured it out with your help. I created a csv with the cumulativ values and used those with a ConstantTimer. Thanks